# How can I implement @Singleton annotation?

Tags: java

Possibly a repeated question. But I need to implement something like

```
@Singleton
public class Person {
}
```

That will ensure only single instance of Person object.

One way is to make constructor private. But that makes the Singleton annotation redundant.

I could not really understand if I can really restrict object creation to single object without making the constructor private.

Is that even possible?

Comment: pretty sure you have to make the constructor private. No annotation is going to stop things from calling the public constructor

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No annotation can prevent a class from being instantiated. However, if you plan to implement something like a Dependency Injection framework, or just a simple object factory, then you can use reflection to read the annotation and prevent the class from being instantiated more than once, but I understand this is not the answer you were looking for.

You can actually think about dropping the singleton pattern and moving to some more modern solution like a proper DI framework, which can give you the same result - with more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of DI as an alternative. But there the container just returns the same bean instance instead of creating it every time when a getBean method is called. I think any one can still instantiate the class by new.

Comment: If the contract of the class includes it shall not be directly instantiated, then you don't necessarily need to enforce this with some programming trick.  If the client wants to violate your contract, let him/her do so and pay the consequences. You were clear enough.

Comment: use Google Guice, https://www.journaldev.com/2403/google-guice-dependency-injection-example-tutorial

Comment: what is https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation ?

Answer (score 12):

```
public class ASingletonClass {

    private static ASingletonClass instance = null;

    private ASingletonClass() {

    }

    public static ASingletonClass getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
             instance = new ASingletonClass();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

This is the right way to implement singleton. The annotation cannot stop people from calling the public constructor.

Comment: @gd1 Which may or may not be required.

Comment: Better to mention. :)

Comment: @gd1 Is there a general way to thread-safe a singleton? Or is it really on a per-implementation basis? Start by making `getInstance()` synchronized?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can initialize the instance immediately upon class initialization (which is guaranteed to be thread-safe), or, if you stick with lazy initialization, you have to make the instance reference volatile (Java 1.5+) and perform double-checked locking. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking . However, this seems so outdated: there are good DI frameworks out there, and they support singleton objects. And most remarkably, they can be turned non-singleton anytime without changing a line of code.

Comment: sometimes DI is just too much. There are many cases where a simple Singleton solves the problem. Need to be open minded here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lazy initialization of the class. Example code as below.

```
class LazyInitialization implements PrintStatement {
   private static LazyInitialization instance;

   private LazyInitialization() {

   }

   static LazyInitialization getInstance() {
     if (instance == null)
        instance = new LazyInitialization();

     return instance;
   }

   @Override
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("I am inside");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is arguably best to have a stateless singleton:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    
    private Singleton() {}
    
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```