# Do annotations for marking a class as singleton or immutable exist in Java 9?

Tags: java, singleton, immutability, java-9

In most programming languages, it is the developer's responsibility to write ***immutable, singleton classes*** etc.

However, I feel like this is kind of ***repeated boilerplate code***. More recent programming languages provide better support for achieving this.

Has Java 9 introduced any annotation or similar construct to mark a class as immutable or singleton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement @Singleton annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795041/how-can-i-implement-singleton-annotation)

Comment: When you are writing so many singletons that you are thinking about how to avoid the associated “boilerplate” (one line of code), you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 9):

No, as far as I know, no such constructs exist in Java 9. Surely that would have been documented in the [list of new features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-5B808B2F-E891-43CD-BF6E-78787E547071).

---

As a side note, Java EE has the [`@Singleton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) annotation, which specifies that a bean is a singleton.

---

As a further side note there exists an extension to [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) called 
[lombok-pg](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg) which has an implementation of a [`@Singleton`](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/%40Singleton) annotation:

```
@Singleton(style=Singleton.Style.HOLDER)
public class SingletonHolderExample {
  private String s;

  public void foo() {
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to the following code:

```
public class SingletonHolderExample {

  private static class SingletonHolderExampleHolder {
    private static final SingletonHolderExample INSTANCE = new SingletonHolderExample();
  }

  public static SingletonHolderExample getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolderExampleHolder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private String s;

  public void foo() {
  }
}
```

Note that Lombok hooks iteslf into the compilation process, and modifies the classes. This is considered by some people as a "hacky" thing to do, and should perhaps be used with causion. Another downside is that you have to modify the IDE in order for it to understand what code Lombok generates. This is done by running the downloaded Lombok jar file.

A good summary of how Lombok works, with its pros and cons, can be found [here](http://notatube.blogspot.se/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html).

Answer (score 4):

In Java EJB you can use @Singleton:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class mySingleton {....}
```

I Usually use it with @Startup as well.

More on Singleton [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: He edited the question to make it specific to Java 9.