# How to force a Java class to have a static method and have only a private constructor?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, singleton

This is probably best achievable through **annotations**.

Something like:

```java
public @interface Singleton {
    // forces classes annotated with it to "override" a static method
    // called `getSingleton` that has its return type as themselves.
}

@Singleton // this class is annotated with the annotation we just defined
public class SomeUniqueThing {
    private static SomeUniqueThing singleton = null;
    public static SomeUniqueThing getSingleton() /* no args */ {
        return singleton == null ? (singleton = new SomeUniqueThing()) : singleton; // lazy
    }
    private SomeUniqueThing {...}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to force a class (for example annotated with something like `@Singleton`) to have only a single no-arg **private constructor** and a **static method** called `getSingleton` that lazily gets an instance of the class.

And then the compiler (in my case **IntelliJ IDEA**) issue a warning if the requirements are not met. For example if the class has a non-private constructor or it does not define that static method.

Please do not suggest the DI approach as it does not help my use cases.

I would also appreciate any resources/links on how to configure annotations in general. I know they can do a lot, I just don't know how. All help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement @Singleton annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795041/how-can-i-implement-singleton-annotation)

Comment: You would need to write your own annotation processor.

Comment: @pringi I actually did see that before asking this and that is why I have said "please do no suggest the DI approach", because that question was resolved with that answer, and the other answers were also not helpful.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am actually doing that as we speak. But it is not easy finding good docs on this topic that can help me configure it considering I'm using Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA. I would appreciate if you knew of any material.

Comment: I don't see how this would be useful, but this will probably help you https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-custom.html